# Prevent processing file until SCP transfer is finished

Tags: files, scp, inotify

Large files are transferred to a server for processing. The server monitors a specific directory using `incrond` and when a new file is received the processing script is executed for that file.

Because the files are large it takes some time to transfer them. How do I make sure that the file has finished transferring before process it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with scp. It's related to
[inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), the kernel interface that's
used to trigger an action on file system events. And you're apparently
triggering on the wrong event. Read the
[man page of incrontab](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=incrontab&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en)
to understand how the system works.

If your processing script already triggers when the file has not been
complete, I assume you trigger on the IN_CREATE event. You can change the
corresponding entry in the `incrontab` to trigger on IN_CLOSE_WRITE.